# iOS delete a tableview row

Tags: ios, row, tableview

I had my app working fine on iOS 6. With the upgrade I stopped being able to delete rows from my `UITableView`.

I've a button in my prototype cell.

**Here is the button's function:**

```
- (IBAction)deleteCell:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*) sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) btn.superview.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    if([names count] > 9) {
        int index = indexPath.row;
        [names removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        [photos removeObjectAtIndex:index];
        [_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    } 
}
```

The problem is my index variable is always 0.

**I tried another solution:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
            int index = indexPath.row;
            [names removeObjectAtIndex:index];
            [photos removeObjectAtIndex:index];
            [_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

}
}
```

This solution doesn't work either. Nothing happens when I swipe right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this sample tutorial,

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
{
  NSMutableArray *arryData1;
  NSMutableArray *arryData2;
  IBOutlet UITableView *tableList;
}

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

 @end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

arryData1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"MCA",@"MBA",@"BTech",@"MTech",nil];
arryData2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Objective C",@"C++",@"C#",@".net",nil];
tableList.editing=YES;

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [arryData1 count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier= @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
}
cell.textLabel.text = [arryData1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [arryData2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    int index = indexPath.row;
    [arryData1 removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    [arryData2 removeObjectAtIndex:index];

    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


}
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (tableList.editing)
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return YES;
}
```

Comment: @ravindran.. if suppose you were to get confirmation from user after pressing the delete button and then deleting the rows is user presses Ok button. How would you do it?

Answer (score 2):

I quess the problem is you're not reloading data again thus it's staying in cache memory

You can try to reload data with `[tableView reloadData];` this method to the below of 
`[_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];`
 this code line in your second solution.

Answer (score 1):

To show delete button on cell swipe you must implement this delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
```

Try this, i hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the tableview commiteditingstyle method to delete a cell/row of the tableviewcontroller.

Here is the workable code snip:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    [ArrayHoldsCellObj removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

Note that the `ArrayHoldsCellObj` is the Array object you must declare and assign each cell to the area index.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the button `tag = cell.index`  in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

And then

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
        [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:btn.tag inSection:0]];
```

so you can get the index

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
//add code here for when you hit delete
[dataSourceArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

}    
}
```

Comment: dataSourceArray is the array from which the cell contents comes