# How to delete row from tableview in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]

I have taken three arrays. One array for saving image data and remaining two arrays image names and dates.

While deleting row I'm getting this error:

> NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

How to handle this?

Comment: Please update your question with your relevant code.

Comment: So you need array to save image data, image name and date, right. Ok, just take a object class with three properties, then add the object class object to array, then manipulate the array, no need to take three different arrays. And your error seems that you are taken NSArray and deleting object from an NSArray, which is not mutable. Take mutable array

Comment: `mutating method sent to immutable object` should make it clear that you are trying to mutate a NSArray whereas you should been using an NSMutableArray instead.

Comment: i have uploaded image can u have see the image please, i'am taking 3 arrays one for images 2nd for image names 3rd one current date i need to delete one image so each row contain 3 objects na how delete this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS delete a tableview row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961581/ios-delete-a-tableview-row)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NSMutableArray instead of NSArray

Answer (score 0):

Simple and optimize way to achieve your functionality

Take a `NSObject` class like

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface YourClassName : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *imgName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData *imgData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *imgDate;

@end
```

Then, add the object of the class to `NSMutableArray`, then mutate it as your wish. Just delete from one array rather than deleting from three different arrays, which is very confusing and may conflicts.

**Or**

Just Use `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSArray`. If you are doing this already, then check `NSMutableArray` contains `NSArray` type values, which can't be immutable.

Thanks

Comment: NSMutableArray *imagesArray;    
NSMutableArray *namesArray;    
NSMutableArray *datesArray;   taking 3 mutable arrays

Comment: why? Just take object class and add the object to a single array. When the array size increases, may cause memory leak issue in future...

Comment: i have taken 3 mutable arrays one array have image data another array image names and third one images dates, see above image iam showing like that . if i wont to delete one image i need to remove that particular row indexes that image data and name and that date ,    if click the delete button it was showing this error "mutating method sent to immutable object'"

Comment: k, that's why I am telling you to create a object class sub-class of NSObject, as I described above. Make one array (NSMutableArray) of objects, having your image data, name and date. In table cell get the object and set in the cell. When remove/delete, just delete that object from the array. Simple

Comment: The error is coming due to lots of complex code you have written. Just avoid that by using array of object

Comment: In commitEditingStyle method, you have written 3 if statements to remove name, image and date. Don't do that, just use array of objects, and one line code to delete i.e [yourObjectArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];